# C++ Code Smell: Incorrect Initializer Braces Placement

Tags: c++, static-analysis, klocwork

I am trying to fix the following code smell within my C++ code generated from Klocwork(KW):

*MISRA.INIT.BRACES: Incorrect initializer braces placement*

Below is a snippet of the code I am attempting to clean this up on.

```
    typedef char charString[10];

    enum SomeEnum
    {
        BLAH1_e,
        BLAH2_e,
        BLAH3_e
    };

    struct ParentStruct
    {
        SomeEnum myEnumValue;
        charString myCharStringValue;
    };

    // This is the the part that KW is not happy about
    // KW complaining about initializer bracer placement
    const ParentStruct myParent[3] = 
    {
        {BLAH1_e, "String1"},
        {BLAH2_e, "String2"},
        {BLAH3_e, "String3"}
    }
```

I've attempted many variations of bracer placement and can't seem to figure out the exact issue with bracer placement I currently have. This doesn't generate any compile errors nor does this have a negative outcome on the code. Maybe it's just KW but just wanted to get some thoughts before I give up completely.

Below is an alternative bracer placement I attempted as well in case someone throws it out as an answer:

```
    // compiles but KW does not like this as well
    const ParentStruct myParent[3] = 
    {
        {BLAH1_e, {"String1"}},
        {BLAH2_e, {"String2"}},
        {BLAH3_e, {"String3"}}
    }
```

Comment: try ` typedef const char charString[10];`Assigning a C style char array to a variable requires const  This is, I think, a change from C++98

Comment: @doug That's when declaring pointers - `char *str = "string";` shouldn't compile anymore, because "string" is a `const char *`. Arrays of characters don't need to be const.

Comment: @Brandon Have you tried constructing a single ParentStruct var, `ParentStruct ps = {{BLAH1_e}, {"String1"}};` in various combinations?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm  Duh. You're right.  Don't see any other problem with the code. Looks perfectly fine.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm  I gave your suggestion a try and still no luck. I even went so far as to reduce the array to a size of 1 and attempted every possible combination of braces I could come up with but still no luck. I'm probably going to have to go back to ignoring this KW code smell...it's something that's been there for a while that I never could figure out.

Comment: The `=` is not necessary. From my experience the C++11 support of Klocwork is miserable. Brace initialization/Uniform initialization is a place where Klocwork often fails and complains that variables are not initialized. So I would not be surprised if the error you get has the same root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Please do run the analysis with the latest version of Klocwork and check if this issue has been reported by Klocwork at your end.

I am using Klocwork 2021.3 and it seems that MISRA.INIT.BRACES checker is not reporting any issue on your code as expected.